# Default constructed std::random_device doesn't return random number

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu-20.04

I tried to run a simple example from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device/random_device) about `std::random_device`, but on the line with function call `d(rd1)` program enters an infinite loop and never returns.

Here is the code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
 
int main()
{
 
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> d(0, 10);
 
    std::random_device rd1;
    for(int n = 0; n < 10; ++n)
        std::cout << d(rd1) << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

After some inspections I found out that the function `std::random_device::operator()` always returns value 4294967295 which causes `std::uniform_int_distribution<IntType>::operator()` to enter an infinite loop.

If I explicitly call constructor with `"rdrand"` or `"/dev/urandom"` program works well, but with `"rdseed"` it's the same wrong result. Also if I link against llvm's libc++ the example works normally. It is worth noting that on Ubuntu 16 and 18 it worked well but on Ubuntu 20 as well as Linux Mint 20 I experienced the issue.

Why is the default constructed random device not working?

`uname -a` output:

```
Linux my-pc 5.4.0-42-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 10 00:24:02 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

and some more info about the system:  [lscpu](https://pastebin.com/AYe4829Z), [lshw](https://pastebin.com/PFfn3DHr)

Comment: The machine doesn't have a source of entropy to draw from. Also, you use `std::random_device` to seed a PRNG, and you feed your PRNG to the distribution.

Comment: It seems like your OS didn't properly initialize your random device. Some script that runs on startup is supposed to make sure this happens.

Comment: Your code works fine for me on Ubuntu 20.04 x86-64 when compiled with `g++ rand.cc`; I get a sequence of 10 numbers that is different on every run.  How exactly do you compile and run your code?

Comment: It may help to run your program under `strace` to see how, if at all, it is gathering entropy to seed the RNG.  On mine it opens `/dev/urandom` and the data it reads is indeed random-looking.

Comment: Does your CPU have a hardware RDSEED instruction? It is documented as being available from Broadwell (Intel) and Zen (AMD) and onward, and if it is available, then CPUID(07h) will set EBX[30].

Comment: Probably related: Some AMD CPUs always generate 0xFFFFFFFF (aka 4294967295 ) as the random number after suspend/resume. https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2019/10/how-a-months-old-amd-microcode-bug-destroyed-my-weekend/ linux patched "/dev/urandom" to use other sources if they detect this

Answer (score 0):

> Why is the default constructed random device not working?

Probably something to do with the quality of implementation, or a problem with the execution environment, or a combination of both. This behaviour is certainly not guaranteed by the standard.

In general, one probably shouldn't rely on randomness of `std::random_device`. At least, combine it with another seed and / or a pseudo random number.